# Not able to perform PUT and DELETE from angular js app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, .htaccess, cors

THis is my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
# If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
# absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
#
# RewriteBase /

# Cross domain access
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type, authorization"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Header add Access-Control-Request-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Request-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type, authorization"
Header add Access-Control-Request-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},last]
```

But when i tries to perform PUT request it gives me error like this.

> :63342/web-wokoshop-partner/index.html?_ijt=vgfnsnd7c4g6l47qh3kt00i8c8#!/suppliers:1
>   XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://abcd.com/SupplierApi/v1/supplier/5.
>   Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

This is How i am making request from angular

```
function updateSupplier(supplier, id) {
    var data = {
        name: supplier.name,
        mobile: supplier.mobile
    };

    var req = {
        method : 'PUT',
        url : REST_SERVICE_URI2 + '/' + supplier.id,
        data : JSON.stringify(data),
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        }
    };


    $http(req).then(
        function(response) {
            alert('supplier updated.');
            console.log(data);
        },
        function(data) {
            consile.log(data);
            alert('update supplier error.');
            alert(data.statusText);

        });

}
```

What is the issue? Am I missing anything?

Comment: try to catch your error and log it by add `.catch((error) => { console.log(error.response) })`

Answer (score 0):

Try this for Delete:- 
$http.delete('Url/Delete', {params: {'Id': Id }})
Try this for Update:- 
$http.put('Url/Update', {params: {'Id': Id }})